# ASP.NET Linq data source - using enum in where parameters

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a linqdatasource and I want to use an enum for Type as below:

```
<asp:linqdatasource id="GridDataSource" runat="server" enabledelete="true" Where="Type == @Type">
    <whereparameters>
        <asp:dynamiccontrolparameter controlid="FilterRepeater" />
        <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="Type" Name="Type" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
    </whereparameters>
</asp:linqdatasource>
```

It keeps throwing an error:

```
Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'ProductType' and 'String'
```

ProductType is my Enum, and String is my input type.  I don't seem to be able to convert one to the other...

Comment: After further investigation, I've found that I can modify the Where clause from "Type == @Type" to "Type == Guid(@Type)" or "Type == datetime(@Type)".  The error thus changes from 'String' to 'Guid' and 'datetime' respectively.  Obviously this is not what I want to achieve but I'm getting somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer - in the where clause

```
Where="Int32(Type) == Convert.ToInt32(@Type)"
```

This is actually a similar problem what can and can't be done inside a linq where clause, and has to do with linq converting to sql.  We can't directly convert enum to string or string to enum, so convert both to int.  The hard part here is realising that you need to do Int32(Type) 
in the linq where clause and (int)Type doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

what does your enum loolk like? Try adding a

`[StringValue("stringValue")]` decorator to each of your enum values

```
public enum ProductType
{
    [StringValue("1")]
    Type1 = 1,
    [StringValue("2")]
    Type2 = 2,
    [StringValue("3")]
    Type3 = 3
}
```

Comment: My enum pretty much looks the same as your exampl.  But I think the error is occurring in the 'linq to sql translation' and it can't do a straight enum == string... I need to convert the string to enum or enum to string somehow